# Couldn't find User with 'id'=#<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f616b692840>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently started to use rails 4 in college and I'm having troubles with deleting a user I created.

It always sais 'Couldn't find User with 'id'=#:' or  'Couldn't find User without Id'.

I looked up a few solutions as this problem seems to be pretty common but nothing worked.

My user list(Index) looks like this and at the end of every line there is the delete button.

```
  <% @user.each do |u| %>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <%= u.username %> <%= u.email%>  
        <%= link_to 'Delete', user_path(@user), method: :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?'%><br>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

This is my destroy method

```
 def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
    end
  end
```

And thats the root page - I suppose I made mistakes here somewhere in 'match' but I'm not sure

```
  resources :users

  get 'users/index'
  get 'users/new'
  get 'users/login'
  get 'users/resume'
  get 'users/userInformation'
  get 'users/update'

  root 'users#index'

  get 'index'=>'users#index'
  get 'new'=>'users#new'
  get 'login'=>'users#login'
  get 'resume'=>'users#resume'
  get 'userInformation'=>'users#userInformation'
  get 'update'=>'users#update'

  match 'users/:id' => 'users#index', :via => :delete
```

(I'm using Rails4)

Thanks in advance!

Chrizzly

Comment: btw your destroy action should only have 1 destroy statement, you have two, the first will succeed and the second will fail, you need to remove the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over your collection and pass each instance of that collection into your link handler:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', user_path(u), method: :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?'%>
```

Right now you are passing in `@user` into your `user_path` so you're passing in the whole collection, which in this case is an ActiveRecord Relation, not the individual User instance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try users_path instead of user_path. 
You can find all the routes and their helpers by typing rake:routes in the command line.